# IBM Maximo REST service POST body is ignord

Tags: rest, maximo, oslc

I have tried to create a record  through REST service in IBM Maximo. The problem is that I created the record but I can't assign values to the attributes. Also if the object had a requierd attributes a got this error  BMXAA4195E - A value is required [...].

The problem persists whether I use OSLC or the old rest API.

I have an Object Structure called RESTOS that represents my customized object.

I did a POST using POSTMAN to this URL: http://hostname:port/maximo/oslc/os/RESTOS?lean=1

In the body section this is the JSON I was trying to send:

```
{
"ATTR1": "value1,
"ATTR2": "value2"
}
```

The problem persists whether I use OSLC or the old rest API.